# How to use blackboard bold numbers with the Palatino (mathpazo) font?

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, mathbb

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}    
Hello world $\mathbb{012345}$    
\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image]

While removing the `mathpazo` package I get

[image]

How can I have it both ways? I would like to use the Palatino font, but at the same time use blackboard-bold numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options.

#### The `mathalpha` Package

This package contains both a `pazo` and a `px` blackboard bold alphabet, matching `mathpazo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[bb=pazo]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}
\( ABC \mathbb{ABC} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Pazo font sample]

You could also replace the `mathalpha` option `bb=pazo` with `bb=px`.  The latter comes with a bold double-struck alphabet usable as `\mathbbb`.  Since `mathpazo` is a fork of Adobe’s version of Palatino, any font package matching Palatino matches it.  See [the `mathalpha` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) for the complete list of alphabets.

#### The `newpxmath` Package

This is essentially an upgrade to `mathpazo`.  It still uses legacy 8-bit fonts, instead of the more modern Unicode and OpenType, but it’s compatible with PDFLaTeX.  It includes a much broader repertoire of symbols, including several double-struck alphabets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\( ABC \mathbb{ABC} \\
   \varmathbb{ABC} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Newpx font sample]

This comes with three different blackboard-bold alphabets, which are controlled by [package options to `newpxmath`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newpx/doc/newpxdoc.pdf).  If you like the letters on the second line, you can make those the default with `\usepackage[varbb]{newpxmath}`, or you can substitute math alphabets with `mathalpha`.

Since `newpx`, like `mathpazo`, is a clone of Palatino, you can match it with any other Palatino clone (such as `tgpagella`) or a font matching Palatino (such as Hermann Zapf’s other masterpieces, Optima and Euler).

#### The Modern Toolchain

If you are able to use `unicode-math` and a modern TeX engine, I personally recommend it.  Asana Math is a modern, Unicode math font based on `mathpazo`.  TeX Gyre Pagella Math is also similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\( ABCabc \\
   \mathbb{ABCabc}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Asana Math sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\( ABCabc \\
   \mathbb{ABCabc}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math sample]

If you wanted to use just the blackboard-bold alphabets of TeX Gyre Pagella Math, and other symbols from Asana Math, you can do that with

```
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={bb,bbit}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

Or vice versa.  If you have an authentic copy of Palatino on your system, you can also use that as your text font instead of the clone, Pagella.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\let\altmathbb\mathbb
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}    
Hello world $\altmathbb{012345}$    
\end{document}
```

[image]

To restore the original so that no syntax variant is required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\let\altmathbb\mathbb
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\altmathbb}
\begin{document}    
Hello world $\mathbb{012345}$  
\end{document}
```

Comment: so is the reason that `mathpazo` overwrites the definitions in `bbold`? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @glS I did not actually look, but presumed this to be the case.  And the MWE seems to bear that out.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought that if that was the case, including `bbold` after `mathpazo` would have fixed it. Anyway, is there a way to still use `\mathbb` instead of having to use a new syntax (`altmathbb` in your answer)?

Comment: @glS See edit..